# Make a live editor that formats text & colors

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to make a live text editor that will allow all text surrounded in square brackets to be highlighted as code. `[example]`

How can I pull the text from the editing `<div>` and replace all `[text]` like so with a code element?

**Eg:**
Replace `[word]` with `<code>[word]</code>`.

This is what I have in regards to the editing window:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="edit">
    The big <code>[color]</code> fox jumped over the lazy <code>[animal]</code>.
</div>
```

**The big `[color]` fox jumped over the lazy `[animal]`.**

I've made this little bit of JS but it doesn't do anything:

```
EDIT = document.getElementById("edit");

EDIT.onkeypress = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 221) {
        var text = EDIT.innerText;
        EDIT.innerHTML = text.replace(/\[([\w\s]+)]/g, "<code>[$1]</code>");
    }
};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a little bit of regex to do it.

Other than this, I can't think of a way to accomplish what I want. And even this doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. This is way too broad for the site. To answer this question as-is would require writing up a massive tutorial which is unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the inner html of the div, search for an open bracket, and then index it to the closing bracket, add those indices to an array, do that for each open/close set, and then read those indices out of the array, and highlight the characters that fell within those index bounds?

I'd give you a better answer, but I don't have enough info to go off of, you haven't mentioned the stack you're using, JavaScript libraries, etc. so that's the best I can give you.

Comment: Vanilla everything.

Comment: I see, okay yeah then I would say what I said above would be about your only option, the only one that isn't overkill anyway.